# Functions signatures differences C++

Tags: c++11

Could you explain me which are the differences between these three functions signatures? Why can auto be used as returned data type and not in parameters declarations?

```
//auto f1(auto x) { return x; }   not accepted

auto f1(int x) { return x; }

auto f2(double x) -> decltype(x) { return x; }

template <typename T> 
T f3(T x) { return x; }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main task of the [**auto**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto) specifier from C++11 is to **deduce** the type of a given value at **compile time**.

```
auto A = 12;        // A deduced type is int
auto B = 4.3;       // B deduced type is double
auto C = "hello";   // C deduced type is const char*
```

Those are all valid cases where auto can be used since it can easily find out the type of the **given** values.

Something like this would be illegal:

```
auto D;
```

since there's no *given value*.

With functions, nothing changes.

```
void foo(auto var) { }
```

When the compiler generates your function **foo**, it has absolutely no idea what type to replace that **auto** with.

Conversely, the other three functions are all valid since the compiler is able to recognize the type.

> Could you explain me which are the differences between these three functions signatures?

**1.**

```
auto f1(int x) { return x; }
```

The return type of **f1** is the same type of the returned value **x**

**2.**

```
auto f2(double x) -> decltype(x) { return x; }
```

The return type of **f2** depends on the type of the parameter **x** since we are using a so called **[trailing return type](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype)**

It is particurarly useful when returning a type that has to be deduced from an expression

```
template<typename T, typename U>
auto foo(T a, U b) -> decltype(a+b) { ... }
```

Here the return type will be the type generated by the sum between the parameters **a** and **b**

```
int a = 10 
double b = 2.3 
return type = int + double = double

char a = 'y';
char b = 'o';
return type = char + char = int
```

**3.**

```
template <typename T> 
T f3(T x) { return x; }
```

Here T evaluates to just one type, and it will be the same for the parameter and the return type.

```
f3("hello");
```

Here **T** evaluates to **const char*** so both the parameter **x** and the return type will automatically be const char*

Answer (score 0):

- `f1` takes an `int` and returns an `int`. (`auto` is deduced to `int` here, since the return expression `x` has type `int`.)
- `f2` takes a `double` and returns a `double`. (This uses a *trailing return type*, where `decltype(x)` evaluates to `double` since `x` is of type `double`.)
- `f3` is a template, and will be instantiated with the given parameter type assigned to `T`, thus it returns the same type. (The function body must compile with the given type `T` for the function to be instantiated.)

> Why can auto be used as returned data type and not in parameters declarations?

Because that's how the language is defined. Also `auto` is not a data type, it's a placeholder for a deduced type.

Answer (score 0):

`auto` doesn't really exist as a type, it is replaced with specific type during compilation. So it can be only used when the compiler can determine single specific type to use in place of the `auto` keyword. It can not be used as form of generics to generate multiple variants of a function.

- `auto f1(auto x) { return x; }   // not accepted`

What type is `auto` in this case? It could be anything. Compiler can not decide which type to put there to finish the signature of `f1`. The compiler is not allowed to make multiple variants like templates can do.

- `auto f1(int x) { return x; }`

`auto` can be derived to be `int`, all good.

- `auto f2(double x) -> decltype(x) { return x; }`

`auto` can be derived to be `double`, all good.

- `template <typename T> T f3(T x) { return x; }`

`f3` is templated, so it doesn't really exist until you use it. When you use it, the compiler will create a variant where the `T` is the type you use in the moment.